# Export Java project to Jar with images

Tags: java, image, jar, executable-jar, getresource

I coded very simple app with has only 2 class and I would lika export this to .JAR, but I have problem with images. When I running in Eclipse it's not problem (image working), but after export I don't see any images.
Images path: res/images/...
In Jar archive is included folder Images with images files.
I try find soluton for this here and google, but I can't :(
I try method getResource, but still is not working.

This is my code.
Main class: https://codeshare.io/5w089R
Secand class: https://codeshare.io/2KQXWE

Someone can halp me and say what I did wrong? Thank for support.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] rather than linking to code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it doesnt work, because it cant find the path. If you create the jar the path "res/images/" gets packaged into the jar. Create the directory one step up from the program and it should work so the directory structure would look like this

```
- My Project
   -myproject.jar
   -images
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to do `InputStream in = this.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(path);`
 then convert the stream to byte array. then use new IconImage(bytearray). 
[look here for different ways to convert](http://www.baeldung.com/convert-input-stream-to-array-of-bytes)..... i like IOUtils.toByteArray